# Problems converting variable into proper datetime format in R

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp, chron

My data, DATA, has a variable, TIME, for which the values print out in this format: "11/14/2006 20:10". For TIME, its mode is numeric and its class is a factor.

I need to convert TIME to a proper date/time variable (DTIME) and add the new DTIME to DATA as date.time. I was told I may have to coerce the time values so that they follow the h:m:s format...Think character string manipulation. Below is my code:

```
 library("chron")

VAR=c(as.character(DATA$TIME))
DT<-t(as.data.frame(strsplit(VAR," ")))
DT[1:3,]
row.names(DT)<-NULL
DT[1:3,]
DTIME<-chron(dates=DT[,1],times=DT[,2],
        format=c("m/d/y","h:m"))
```

But once I run the last line of code, I get the following error message:

```
Error in convert.times(times., format = format[[2]]) : 
  format h:m may be incorrect
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(out$s) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

I don't understand what this means, much less how to fix it.

Comment: there appears to be a bug in `chron:::parse.format` called by `chron:::convert.times` whereby the format 'h:m' is not parsed correctly, whereas (say) 'h:m:s' *is* parsed correctly. not sure where that would be reported but in the meantime using `as.chron` as suggested in one of the answers below seems a good workaround

Comment: That would be a desirable feature but it is not a bug.  Its documented in `?chron` that the times format must be a permutation of `h`, `m` and `s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not clear from the question exactly what you have -- in such cases its best to show the output of `dput` applied to your variable -- but assuming you can convert it to character format using `as.character` or `format` then its just a matter of using `as.chron` :

```
> library(chron)
> TIME <- "11/14/2006 20:10"
> as.chron(TIME, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
[1] (11/14/06 20:10:00)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `lubridate` - it's a fantastic library that will save you much effort.

```
library(lubridate)
x <- "11/14/2006 20:10"
> mdy_hm(x)
[1] "2006-11-14 20:10:00 UTC"
```

All `lubridate`'s time conversion function follow a very similar pattern: e.g. `"2013-04-01"` can be parsed with `ymd`, etc.

Comment: That does seem WAY easier. Unfortunately, I was specifically told to use the chron package. But I will definitely use this for my own reference!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `as.POSIXct` to convert string into time.

```
TIME <- "11/14/2006 20:10"
as.POSIXct(TIME, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz='GMT')
## [1] "2006-11-14 20:10:00 GMT"
```

Comment: R is telling me that the POSIX package "is not available (for R version 2.15.3)"

Comment: You don't need any package for this. as.POSIXct is a base function.